# Insert text into blank lines in bash

Tags: bash, text, awk, echo

It's possible to insert text in order into the blank lines in txt (txt file can contain hundreds of items) use bash?

First file

```
text1

text2

text3

text4

textn...

#and etc
```

Second file

```
text1b
text2b
text3b
textbn...
#and etc
```

Output:

```
text1
text1b
text2
text2b
text3
text3b
text4
textbn...
textn...
#and etc
```

Comment: Unclear what are you asking. Are `text1b` a copy of the previous line plus a `b`? That would be easy to do. Also: **What have you tried?**

Comment: I would say it is a bad question. 1) where does `textnb` come? 2), if there are continuous empty lines, what do you want to do? 3) if there are empty line(s) at the BOF, what do you want to do. I don't like those question poster, after getting an answer, change the requirement 10 times to break got answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed and this two files:

file1:

```
text1

text2

text3

text4
```

file2:

```
text1b
text2b
text3b
```

This command:

```
sed -e '/^$/{R file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

Output

```
text1
text1b
text2
text2b
text3
text3b
text4
```

---

From `man sed`:

> `R filename`: Append a line read from filename.  Each invocation of  the  command  reads  a line from the file.  This is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 0):

In awk, for example having a counter `i`:

```
$ awk '/^$/ && ($0= "text" ++i "b") || 1' file
text1
text1b
text2
text2b
text3
text3b
text4
text4b
textn...
text5b
#and etc
```

or by copying the previous record and appending `b`:

```
$ awk '/^$/ { $0=p "b" } p=$0' file
text1
text1b
text2
text2b
text3
text3b
text4
text4b
textn...
textn...b
#and etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work robustly, efficiently and portably in any awk on any UNIX system:

```
awk 'FNR==1{a[NR]=$0;next} {print (NF ? $0 : a[FNR])}' file2 file1
```