# How insert text into blank lines in any cases?

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I would like to paste the text from `File2` into `File1`

File1:

```
1
2

4
5

7
8
```

File2:

```
3
6
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

As example attempt from this question [Insert text into blank lines in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503222/insert-text-into-blank-lines-in-bash):

```
sed -e '/^$/{R file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

But it works only in case where there is only every second line blank. I would like to ask, it's possible in more complex cases? In other words, is there a universal solution?

As example:

File1

```
1
2
3

5
6


9
```

File2

```
4
7
8
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Using GNU sed your sed script works fine for me in the second example, after taking care that `File1` and `File2` end with single newline. E.g.: take care to hit Return once after the `8` and the `9`.

Comment: By a 'universal solution' do you mean 1) take two files, 2) combine, 3) sort 4) eliminate blanks? You can do `cat f1 f2 | sort | grep .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this awk script:

**script.awk**

```
FNR == NR  { repl[ ++i ] = $0;  next; }
NF == 0    { print repl[ ++j ]; next; }
1
```

Run it like this: `awk -f script.awk File2 File1`.

**Explanation**

- The first line with the condition `FNR == NR` is executed only while reading the first file given as argument. Here it is `File2`. It stores the replacement line in `repl` and reads the next line from `File2`, due to `next` statement.
- The second and third line are executed for the second file given as argument, here it is `File1`.

  - The condition `NF == 0` is true for blank lines and prints the next available replacement line from `repl`, then reads the next line from `File1`
  - The `1` is *excuted* for non blank lines from `File1` and it is a shortcut for printing the line.

Comment: @EdMorton I updated the script, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using awk and `getline`:

```
$ awk 'NF==0{ getline < "file2" }1' file1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

9
```

Extra empty line is a test with more gaps in `file1` as there are values in `file2`.

Comment: this might be a good use of `getline`.  `!NF` will be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy for any case**  with **Perl one-lnier**

If you change your file_2 into a file without **newline** it is an easy job to do.

[image]

---

```
$ cat file_1
1
2
3

5
6


9
$ cat file_2
3 7 8
$
$ perl -ale '@file2=@F if $.==1; print ( /\d+/ ? @F : shift @file2 ) if $.!= 1' file_2 file_1 
1
2
3
3
5
6
7
8
9
```

**how it works**

The main part is here:
`print ( /\d+/ ? @F : shift @file2 )`
that it pops the **file2** if the line does not match any digit. that is it.
Also you can change the **@F** to **$_**
`print ( /\d+/ ? $_ : shift @file2 )`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just fill an array and then print out the indexes supplied:

```
awk 'NF{a[$1]}END{for( i in a )print i}' file1 file2
```

Comment: because that won't print the values in the order read/desired it'll print the values from both files in random (hash) order. You may as well just do `awk 'NF' file1 file2`.

Comment: No ... your solution would print them in the order they appear in the files. Mine will display them in numerical order.

Comment: No it will not, you can read about the `in` operator at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array: `The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array elements within awk`. In other words the order they are accessed is the order they are stored in the hash tables which for all intents you can consider random.

Comment: Agreed, although I have rarely had issue, but an asorti should do the trick ;)

Comment: asroti() would make it gawk-specific and if you're using gawk you could use PROCINFO["sorted_in"] instead but there's simpler more portable ways to do the job and at the end of the day we're trying to make a silk purse out of a sows ear - it's just the wrong approach for this problem.